# dplyr filter with multiple conditions and OR

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a large tibble that I need to reduce by filtering. Specifically I need to filter different combinations of multiple conditions (but all from the same columns).

My filter condition are something like

```
  filter(str_detect(id, "^M.+(KIT|FLEECE)"), between(f1, 300, 400),  between(f2, 1300, 1400))
 filter(str_detect(id, "^M.+(GOOSE)"), between(f1, 200, 350),  between(f2, 1200, 1400))
```

What of course works is something like

```
filtered1<- df %>%
  filter(str_detect(id, "^M.+(KIT|FLEECE)"), between(f1, 300, 400),  between(f2, 1300, 1400))
filtered2<- df %>%
  filter(str_detect(id, "^M.+(GOOSE)"), between(f1, 200, 350),  between(f2, 1200, 1400))
filtered<-bind_rows(filtered1, filtered2)
```

I'm wondering how I would combine these with some sort of OR statement like

```
  filtered<- df %>%
    filter(str_detect(id, "^M.+(KIT|FLEECE)"), between(f1, 300, 400),  between(f2, 1300, 1400)) OR
    filter(str_detect(id, "^M.+(GOOSE)"), between(f1, 200, 350),  between(f2, 1200, 1400))
```

Here is an MWE of some sample data

```
id<-rep(c("M1_1_KIT_1", "M3_2_FLEECE_2", "M2_4_GOOSE_3", "M6_4_KIT_5"), 3)
f1<-sample(200:500, 12)
f2<-sample(1200:1500, 12)
df<-data.frame(id, f1, f2)
df

          id  f1   f2
1     M1_KIT 268 1238
2  M3_FLEECE 270 1459
3   M2_GOOSE 409 1471
4     M4_KIT 344 1337
5     M1_KIT 400 1419
6  M3_FLEECE 210 1379
7   M2_GOOSE 321 1356
8     M4_KIT 478 1284
9     M1_KIT 391 1439
10 M3_FLEECE 382 1317
11  M2_GOOSE 468 1273
12    M4_KIT 306 1270
```

I would be even more happy for a more general solution, like where I put the filter values into a separate tibble and iterate over the rows, but that is beyond my R knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

You can put them in parentheses using `&` and then use the pipe `|` to mean "or"

```r
df %>%
  filter(
    (str_detect(id, "^M.+(KIT|FLEECE)") & between(f1, 300, 400) & between(f2, 1300, 1400)) |
    (str_detect(id, "^M.+(GOOSE)") & between(f1, 200, 350) & between(f2, 1200, 1400))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

For better readability (although the solution by @yake84 is totally ok), I suggest to put the conditions into variables with intuitive names. To illustrate, see this example (of course, f1_/f2_ should be replaced by their meaning):

```
f1_high <- between(f1, 300, 400)
f1_low <- between(f1, 200, 350)
f2_high <- between(f2, 1300, 1400)
f2_low <- between(f2, 1200, 1400)

df %>%
  filter(
    (str_detect(id, "^M.+(KIT|FLEECE)") & f1_high & f2_high) |
    (str_detect(id, "^M.+(GOOSE)") & f1_low & f2_low)
  )
```

This naming is very helpful if you have to work over your code a few months later, or need someone else to collaborate on. The value ranges might change, but you don't need to change the code but only the variable assignments.